# Setup FreeRADIUS on windows

Tags: windows, freeradius

Can any one suggest where to download "FreeRADIUS" server (2.2.3) .exe for windows?

- I tried downloading 1.1.7 from [Downloads | FreeRADIUS](http://freeradius.net/Downloads.html). It works fine but it doesn't work for TLS security.
- The WIFI module provider suggested that download 2.2.3 version and it will work.
- I tried searching internet through out but could not get the .exe of setup.

Comment: Are you using Windows Server? Because if so, just deploy NDES and a local PKI from the AD CS service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FreeRADIUS is not distributed for Windows. I did find [WinRADIUS](http://winradius.eu/) which looks like it's a Windows port of FreeRADIUS.